# bash script in unix - return full path and filename

Tags: unix, bash, return-path

I want to design bash script in unix and this bash return full path because I want to use this file in other places.

Comment: Full path of what? Self, as in the full path of the running script or some other object? A text string passed to your script as an argument?

Comment: critically you did not say whether you are executing or sourcing the script as it imparts very different approaches to solving the path question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the full path and filename of the running script?

```
#!/bin/bash
```

_my_name=`basename $0`

if [ "`echo $0 | cut -c1`" = "/" ]; then

```
 _my_path=`dirname $0`
```

else

```
 _my_path=`pwd`/`echo $0 | sed -e s/$_my_name//`
```

fi

echo "     Filename: $_my_name"

echo "Absolute path: $_my_path"

echo "Full Path + Name: $0"

Comment: @Osama Ahmad: See [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try if you have `readlink` on your system:

```
readlink -e filename
```

Comment: i try to execute it and this is a result ` readlink:  not found`

Comment: `readlink` is not on every un*x (it's specific to gnu)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is *not* trying to answer the harder question of converting a path with symbolic links into a physical path (w/o any links), but rather just get the directory and/or full path to the original script, there is a simpler solution (broken down in this example into components for legibility, plus you may want to use any of these pieces individually):

```
#!/bin/bash
PROG_PATH=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}      # this script's name
PROG_NAME=${PROG_PATH##*/}       # basename of script (strip path)
PROG_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "${PROG_PATH:-$PWD}")" 2>/dev/null 1>&2 && pwd)

echo "script directory is: $PROG_DIR"
```

Your test cases should involve calling this script with an absolute path, relative path, "sourcing" it, etc., and always ending up with the directory containing the script.